# Rewrite rule not working as expected?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL with a parameter which I wish to make into sef URL:

want:

```
http://map.tautktiv.com/street.php?address=abc
```

to become:

```
http://map.tautktiv.com/street/address/abc
```

or

```
http://map.tautktiv.com/address/abc
```

have tried several online tools to generate a `.htaccess` rule, but none of them have any effect on the URL, `.htaccess` file is active (tried to put some gibberish in it and got error 500)

these are the rules I tried:

1.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^address-([^-]*)$ /street.php?address=$1 [L]
RewriteRule street/address/(.*) street.php?address=$1
```

2.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /address/(.*)\.php street.php?address=$1
```

3.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# add whatever other special conditions you need here

RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)-(.*)$ /street.php?address=$1 [L]
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/$ street.php?address=$1
```

the site is a sub-domain which files reside in a sub directory in a shared hosting GoDaddy server, have also tried to apply these rules to the `.htaccess` in the directory above it, same result.

tried also this per below suggestions

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^street/address/(.*)$ street.php?address=$1 [r=301,L]
RewriteRule ^address/(.*)$ street.php?address=$1 [r=301,L]
RewriteRule ^street/address/(.*)$ street.php?address=$1 [r=301,L]
```

same result, nothing happens.

tried to go directly to page from main domain but same result:

```
http://tautktiv.com/map/streets/street.php?address=abc
```

Comment: The first one seems correct-ish at first glance. The second rule in the first block should be surrounded with `^` and `$` to prevent it from matching `foo/street/address/asdf`. Try adding `RewriteBase /` above the rules. Note that these are internal rewrites, to make `http://example.com/street/address/asdf` display an actual page. They don't work the other way around.

Comment: @buzibuzi You're misunderstanding how this method is supposed to work. You should be visiting `http://map.tautktiv.com/street/address/abc` which would then return the content of `http://map.tautktiv.com/street.php?address=abc` (without the url changing to that)

Comment: you are right...take a look at Prix's answer, he fixed that one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule will redirect your ugly URL to the pretty URL.
Second rule will internally redirect it back so the user will not see the ugly URL.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Internally forward /street/address/abc to /street.php?address=abc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^street/address/(.*)/?$ /street.php?address=$1 [NC,L]

# Internally forward /address/abc to /street.php?address=abc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^address/(.*)/?$ /street.php?address=$1 [NC,L]
```

If you confirm the rule to be working as expected then you can change it from 302 to 301 as you do not want to use 301 until you know the rule is working as expected.

**The `.htaccess` should go inside the folder where `street.php` is located.**

HTTP is US ASCII so your language would fail, it will redirect it to something like this:

> /street/address/%25D7%2590%2520%25D7%2598%25D7%2591%25D7%25A8%25D7%2599%2520%25D7%2599%25D7%25A8%25D7%2595%25D7%25A9%25D7%259C%25D7%2599%25D7%259D%2520%25D7%2599%25D7%25A9%25D7%25A8%25D7%2590%25D7%259C

Your best bet here would be to change the links to use `/street/address/word` instead of the php file directly.

This way you would not need the first rule and you can use only the internal redirect which would work just fine with this update.

Comment: great! its partially working: when you go directly to the url : http://map.tautktiv.com/street.php?address=abc - then it works.
but when clicking on links from within the site,or refreshing the page you are already in, it doesnt rewrite.
for example - try anyone of the links on http://map.tautktiv.com/street-index.php   
- also try to refresh the page after loading it. any ideas why ? i tried using a "no-cache" header and making the urls with the full domain but it didn't do much. (btw, the pages are written in PHP)
thanks

Comment: @buzibuzi the problem is the language you're using I've changed the code to work with it but carefully read the bottom of my answer as of what will happen.

Comment: your suggestion is good. but there is still a problem: if the parameter passed in "address=" is a Hebrew string, it doesn't pass to the $_REQUEST var in street.php, english strings are passed ok. is this have to do with the language issue ? any way around it ? thanks for your help

Comment: @buzibuzi nor it will ever pass as HTTP is US ASCII, it will always convert arabic/hebrew like characters like that so you dont have to use the first rule just the last 2 rules and not display on your site links with query string, just make the links as directories as it would be done by the first rule. For example: `map.tautktiv.com/address/א ד ג פתח תקווה ישראל`

Comment: @buzibuzi [if this answer helped u kindly mark it as the right answer, see here how.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: the url is fine, but the parameter is not passed to the page - i can't use it to run geocoding on the address ($address = $_REQUEST['address'] comes out empty). is this final ?

Comment: @buzibuzi like I have said you cannot use arabic/hebrew language as it is NOT supported and it will be converted to encoded variable when using the flag `B` or empty when not so yes it is final. You need to use it backwards without redirecting the php to the directory format. Being that said you only need the last 2 rules on the above answer.

Comment: sorry but that doesn't work either.
i formatted the links as directory and used the last rule. but the Hebrew is still not showing up in the $_REQUEST. tested it with english variable and the variable does pass. 
try anyone of the links here : http://map.tautktiv.com/street-index.php and see the map doesn't goto the address.  plenty of hebrew websites use SEF structure and pass the variable to the page, why doesn't this one work ?  
 thanks

Comment: @buzibuzi [**very simple example that shows the last 2 rules work as expect**](http://i.imgur.com/IBgkIYX.png) as you can see on the image I am using the URL `address/א-נדא טירה ישראל` from your site on my own test domain, as you can see on the result page it captures the address into the PHP variable address as expected. What you are doing wrong on your code is a different question. Since I am using PHP to get the address all I had to do was use `$_GET['address']`.

Comment: i noticed the problem was the rule wasn't working at all, the browser just went to index.php because its the default page not because of the rule. for some very strange reason, after changing the word "address" to "map" in the SEF structure it suddenly started to work. go figure...  thanks for your help

Comment: @buzibuzi maybe you had more rules or other .htaccess files and one of it could be interfering with it would have to look at it to know. Either way glad its working well for u now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^street/address/(.*)$ street.php?address=$1 [r=301,L]
RewriteRule ^address/(.*)$ street.php?address=$1 [r=301,L]
```

In your examples you'd missed `^` and `$` in the second row of RewriteRule.

And use `[r=301,L]` instead of `[L]` to tell the browser, that thzis is premanent redirecting.