# Rewrite rule returning empty $_GET parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

continuing from the point where [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143546/rewrite-rule-not-working-as-expected/18148966#18148966) was answered,

im using this rule in my .htaccess file:

```
# Internally forward /map/abc to /location.php?address=abc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^map/(.*)/?$ /location.php?address=$1 [NC,L]
```

moving on, at some point after the page has loaded, a user performs a facebook login which redirects back to this originating page but adds an authentication code:

```
 map/פבריגט/חולון/ישראל?code=Facebook_Auth
```

problem is "Code" parameter is not passed.

i tried to add this rule before the first rule mentioned above:

```
#first rule to Internally forward /map to /location.php?address=abc&code=yxz and get code
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^map/(.*)/?(.*)$ /location.php?address=$1&code=$2 [NC,L]
```

but for this url:

```
/map/פבריגט/חולון/ישראל?code=abc
```

the $_GET array outputs

```
'address' => string UTF-8 (18) "פבריגט/חולון/ישראל"
'code' => string (0) ""
```

what rule should i use to intercept the "code" parameter ?
any help will be welcome.
Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need additional `QSA` flag (Query String Append) in your `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteRule ^map/(.*?)/?$ /location.php?address=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```